# How to create an Isometric tile-map with 3D objects

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, sprite-kit, scenekit

So, I am building a basic tycoon game. In this game I want to have a simplex 3D generated tile-map that the player can build on. I need the tile-map to be 3D (or have a 3D appearance) because I want to be able to use some realistic shaders on the 3D models the player is going to be able to build.

At first, I thought I could combine SpriteKit and SceneKit. I would generate the 2D SKTileMapNode and then allow the player to build the 3D buildings on top of that. But that wouldn't work as well because SKTileMapNodes aren't easily pannable or zoomable.

My second idea was to build an SKTileMap randomly (which I know how to do easily) and then use that as a reference to build a 3D scene. That would allow me to have full control over what goes where, but there is a catch. Each 3D block (representing a tile in the tileMap) would be treated as a node and cause huge performance issues, Unlike SpriteKits SKTileMapNode that treats the tile-map as a single large node once it is filled with the tiles.

I would prefer to not use an isometric SKTileMap because that wouldn't allow the player to be able to pan/zoom the map and thus, reduce the depth and feel that I would like to achieve with this game.

For instance, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flZ6qZuTiSI) is what I am going for (similar in build but completely different in style)

Comment: Definitely a job for SceneKit. Your question is rather broad, I think you would get better responses if you were to ask help with a specific issue you have setting this up in Scenekit.

Comment: Im just asking for the "best" method to achieve this. I can delete this question and ask again later when I get to the world generating stage. Right now I am just planning the various buildings and what purposes they serve. (like power plants and dormitories etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Each 3D block (representing a tile in the tileMap) would be treated as a node and cause huge performance issues,”

I think your question should be “how to render a 3D tile map with good performance in Scenekit” because imo Scenekit is definitely the way to go here and it is certainly doable to prevent those “huge performance issues”.

For starters, how do you create a tile? If you use the builtin primitives you can get a huge performance increase by using a tile from a dae or obj file, or even by creating it programmatically.

If the tile is the same model throughout, you should add it only once, and then clone it for all the other tiles:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408046-clone
(Note you will have to create a copy of the material and assign it to a clone to prevent it from being shared across all tiles).

Additionally, by adding them all to a single parent node, you can create a socalled flattened clone to combine all the tiles into a single node.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407960-flattenedclone which significantly reduces the number of draw calls.

If that isn’t fast enough, another option is to create the entire map programmatically. That is, create all the vertices and create a SCNGeometry based on those.

Yet another, probably blazing fast option, would be to use 4vertices to create a plane, and then use a shader and displacement map to create the tiled map.

The part about cloning and flattened clones also applies to the buildings that have the same geometry.

And just for completeness, in case that wasn't obvious, you should set the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1436621-usesorthographicprojection property of the camera to true to get that isometric look.

Comment: Very useful answer! :) What if I want variations in the terrain, like water and different variations on the grass? (and other "tiles" I will include) If you take a look at the video I linked you'll notice that the map has different variations in the tiles of the map. Also the camera will be pannable so the isometric look won't make a difference.

Comment: If those variations are in the geometry you would probably still have many tiles that are the same, which then should be clones and/or “flattened” together. If the geometry of the tile is the same each clone can still have its own unique material assigned to it and then you can still flatten them into a single node. If there are many many variations in tiles but a limited amount of maps, it might just be better to model and texture the entire map in 3d modeling software.

Comment: I don’t see how a pannable camera makes up for orthographic projection. Without that property on, tiles in the distance will be smaller than tiles in the front, which also based on the example isn’t what you want.

Comment: Exactly, I didn't know what you were talking about until I looked at the link, I don't want that on either. (also I apologize for the YouTuber I linked, it was the first one I could think of. also one of my favorite YouTubers ;)

Comment: In this case `flattenedClone` could kill performance instead of improving it. If the whole world is flattened, SceneKit won't be able to cull objects that are not visible on screen and will always draw everything. This is a huge waste of GPU usage. Additionally, by *not* flattening, SceneKit can efficiently leverage instancing to draw several similar objects in a single draw call.

Comment: Very useful topic. Thanks for that. However, I have a problem with my use of `flattenedClone`. When cloned node is removed from scene in the console appears error message about weak variables. I have created a question for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053254/scenekit-flattenedclone-incorrect-use-of-objc-storeweak-and-objc-loadweak @mnuages @Xartec any hints on that? Help appreciated :)